# Ajax in Jquery does not work from local file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, local

I created simple html file with simple ajax.

**index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; Charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>
        function show()
        {
                $.ajax({
                url: "2.html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#content").html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            show();
            setInterval('show()',1000);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

File **2.html** located in the same directory as the file **index.html**. And contains for example:

```
 <p>ssss hkl jh lkh <b>d1111</b></p>
```

When I run the **index.html** on the webserver, everything works. But if you run file **index.html** on the computer as a local file ajax not working. How to fix it?

Comment: Is `jquery.js` included next to `index.html`?

Comment: Are you in Chrome? Chrome doesn't allow local ajax stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known problem with Chrome, if you are checking on it. Use XAMPP to run a local webserver, and test your ajax call.

Check this ticket: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Comment: Even faster, use Python (of course). In the terminal:

`cd /path/to/project/folder`
then
`> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`


Use http://127.0.0.1:8080/ or a variation your system may desire. (OSX, Py 2.7x)

Comment: Or you could use node.js. 
> npm install -g http-server 
> cd /path/to/project/folder 
> http-server

Answer (score 16):

Some browsers implement strong security measures to prevent downloaded webpages from accessing arbitrary files on the file system.

Switch to a browser with weaker security (I think Firefox permits access to local files via XHR) or stop trying to run a website without HTTP.

Comment: Also with chrome with the following command line :`chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`