# Why Chrome fails to run jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have latest version of google chrome.The following script runs in all browsers except in google chrome. Can anyone give me any suggestion on what to do to run it in chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Developer Console?

Comment: Works in Chrome here.  How have you tried to debug it?

Comment: If you are going to use the antiquated XHTML tag atleast you could learn the correct syntax required for XHTML pages. /rant

Comment: Why do you have two `html` start tags?

Comment: Don't work from the filesystem. Work from a real webserver.

Comment: If you're working with your local file system, restart Chrome using `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files` (close **all** Chrome instances before doing so!).

Comment: JayC in my real file there is only one html tag. It was typed here by mistake

Comment: ComFreek
I have tried your solution, still not working

Comment: @ShahnawazSiddique Thanks for your response, but also answer my first question (first comment), please.

Comment: @ShahnawazSiddique When you say locally, do you mean, `http://localhost/myfile`? if you're actually using `file://.../myfile` then that's why it isn't working. Stop using `file://` (otherwise known as the filesystem) to test ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax in Jquery does not work from local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome by default does not allow ajax requests to access the filesystem. You can get around it by setting an argument in the shortcut that you use to open chrome, however I'd suggest instead just not testing from the filesystem to begin with. It's not too difficult to setup a very basic webserver.

For reference, `file://.../myfile.html` would be considered working from the filesystem, while `http://localhost/myfile.html` would be working from a local webserver.

Comment: This is the exact solution to the problem i faced. Sometimes silly mistakes are made and my problem was one of it. Anyways thanks a lot and now with this solution i can proceed further.

Comment: Everyone is requested to vote UP this answer as I dont have the capability to do that till now.

Comment: @ShahnawazSiddique This answer is technically 100% correct, but I don't know why you don't accept Bucky24's answer. He wrote the answer 6 minutes before Kevin B did. I do not want to influence your answer marks (or blame Kevin B), this decision is totally up to you, but I just want to mention that point in response to your comment.

Comment: @ComFreek The thing is, they are technically two completely different solutions. He tried your solution, but couldn't get it to work. I agree, your solution should have worked, most likely he just didn't close down all of the instances of chrome properly. Which one is first is less important in this case since we've presented two different solutions. He chose which one he felt best answered the question. Realistically this question should have probably been closed as a duplicate