# Unable to make a $http.get request to a local JSON file using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

I'm making a weather application where I need to grab a local JSON file from within my controller and then do stuff with the data. However, I can't get a **local** `$http.get` request to work for some reason. What should I do?

This is my current code:

```
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', []); 

weatherApp.controller('weatherCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cities = [],
    $scope.getCities = (function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:81/Webb/angular projekt/jsons/cities.json')
             .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                 console.log(data);
             })
             .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log(status);
             });
    }())
}
```

Which gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {                                         angular.js:11598
at Object.parse (native)
at oc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:14:156)
at Yb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:77:190)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:78:50
at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:7:302)
at Yc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:78:32)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:79:165)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:112:343
at l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:126:193)
at l.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:123:286)
```

I also tried using `jsons/cities.json` but that throws this error:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Making a get request to an external resource works fine, but whenever I do it locally things just doesn't seem to work.

The JSON file I'm trying to get looks like this:

```
{"cities": {

    {   
        city: "Stockholm", 
        latitud: "59", 
        longitud: "18",
        id: "sthlm"
    }, 
    {
        city: "Göteborg", 
        latitud: "58", 
        longitud: "12",
        id: "gbg"
    },
    {
        city: "Malmö", 
        latitud: "55", 
        longitud: "13",
        id: "malmo"
    },
    {
        city: "Umeå", 
        latitud: "63", 
        longitud: "20",
        id: "umea"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you aren't passing a valid URI.  you can't have spaces in the URI.

Comment: The JSON is malformed too - the keys for each object need to be string escaped, and the cities should be an array.

Comment: @AndrewCounts I get the same result without.

Comment: @surfitscrollit ah right.. Fixing that and testing if it works.

Comment: @AndrewCounts turns out you can have a space in it, it was the JSON file that was wrong apparently. I'm able to get it now.

Comment: It might be sensible to delete the question, as the issue was merely malformed JSON.

Comment: @surfitscrollit Could you post your comment as an answer? I got useful answers that answers the topic but your comment was the thing that solved the issue.

Comment: @rac I think it's better to leave it up since the answers could be useful to other people in the future.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz sure - I've edited my existing answer to indicate the malformed JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your *local* file you're getting a JSON parsing exception because your JSON is severely malformed. Try this format instead:

```
{
    "cities": [
        {
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "latitud": "59",
            "longitud": "18",
            "id": "sthlm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a cross-origin request for local files. Otherwise websites could request files on your computer at will.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file) for more information. Suggested solutions include running a server in your machine so you end up calling the file via HTTP. `file://` just isn't an acceptable *"protocol"* for making AJAX calls.

Comment: Well if Chrome doesn't allow it, how can I force it to allow it? Or how can I get around it?

Comment: Try another browser, possibly an older one, that still allows for XHR to run. Or run this inside a server, even a local one in your computer.

Comment: Try the suggestions on user1515126's answer. Your local server might have a restrictive Access Control policy. And it never hurts to avoid spaces in URL names (`http://localhost:81/Webb/angular projekt/jsons/cities.json`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a relative path instead of an absolute one:

```
$http.get('jsons/cities.json')
```

Or something along those lines, depending on your folder structure.

Edit: [Here's a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KrHjANUvWsiDBaBLLRIT?p=preview) showing it working.

Edit 2: It appears that the issue was actually the JSON being malformed. The correct format would be:

```
{
  "cities": [
    {   
        "city": "Stockholm", 
        "latitud": "59", 
        "longitud": "18",
        "id": "sthlm"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Göteborg", 
        "latitud": "58", 
        "longitud": "12",
        "id": "gbg"
    },
    {
        "city": "Malmö", 
        "latitud": "55", 
        "longitud": "13",
        "id": "malmo"
    },
    {
        "city": "Umeå", 
        "latitud": "63", 
        "longitud": "20",
        "id": "umea"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

'http://localhost:81/Webb/angular projekt/jsons/cities.json' has a space in it. Could you try by eliminating the space between 'angular' and  'projekt'?

> Making a get request to an external resource works fine, but whenever I do it locally things just doesn't seem to work.

Did you set the server's Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to match your request's Origin header? Setting the response header to origin request header works.

Also how do you access your Angular page?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming this will be static data. Define an object and refer to it as a script.

> Include reference into index.html (or whatever)

```
<script src="../jsons/citiesJSON.js"></script>
```

> create an object and pump in the data

```
var GLOBALDATA = {};
GLOBALDATA.citiesJSON =
{"cities": {
{   
    city: "Stockholm", 
    latitud: "59", 
    longitud: "18",
    id: "sthlm"
}, 
{
    city: "Göteborg", 
    latitud: "58", 
    longitud: "12",
    id: "gbg"
},
{
    city: "Malmö", 
    latitud: "55", 
    longitud: "13",
    id: "malmo"
},
{
    city: "Umeå", 
    latitud: "63", 
    longitud: "20",
    id: "umea"
    }
}
} ; // <-- it's a statement now
```

> no need to request the data via HTTP

```
$scope.cities = GLOBALDATA.citiesJson;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use relative path like $http.get('../jsons/cities.json'), but didn't work. Until I add support for .json file in web.config like this

```
<staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      </staticContent>
```