# Load external JSON file into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I tried to import a json file into my html table. But right now it is not working. 
I am not sure if the path is right written like that. Or what i am doing wrong. 
I really hope that someone cane help me.

My JSON file:

```
{
    "_id": "",
    "_rev": "",
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [],
        "type": ""
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "editor": "",
        "OS_Version": "",
        "Make_and_M": "",
        "title": "",
        "Name": "",
        "Species_Id": "",
        "timestamp": ""
    }
}
```

MY HTML Code:

```
$(function() {
    var people = [];
    $.getJSON('\\Users\\betzenben\\Dropbox\\Website\\test.json', function(json) {
        $.each(json.properties, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Species_Id + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.timestamp + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: No i get no error it is just not loading the data

Comment: Unfortunately i have no idea why

Comment: I think problem is to access local file, it's not allowed

Comment: how do you mean that ? is there any way how i can access a local file ?

Comment: Try to use some locale web server to develop your stuff

Comment: that makes sense i will try that thank you

Comment: You can use the SimpleHTTPServer in Python to serve files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax in Jquery does not work from local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the file on your webserver. The file needs to be accessed like http://yourserver/file.json.
Also, make sure your webserver supports the .json mime-type, otherwise use .js

You can access local files only if you are in back-end (nodejs for example), otherwise you can't.

Javascript is running on the client-side (in the browser), and you can't access the user filesystem (that will be a security issue)

Comment: Thank you i will do that

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to use jsonp to get access on a foreign domain (Same-Origin-Policy).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't think this applies. Check the URI: `\\Users\\betzenben\\Dropbox\\Website\\test.json` that looks like a folder