# issues with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, angular-ui-router

I'm basically trying to create a simple front-end routing system using angularJS(v1.5.5) and angular-ui-router(CDN v0.2.15).

However I keep getting returned this error in my google chrome console and I can't understand why it is happening:

The error that keep's being returned by my console, when I switch ng-view for ui-view that's when the error is occurring I think.

[XML Error and my Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEoyb.png)

[app.js and my controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFtc7.png)

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: are you opening the files from filesystem?

Comment: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17948532/1505865)

Comment: Use a server to serve the files over http e.g : https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server

Comment: it's usually happens when you don't use a server,or the server don't serve your xmlHttp request

Comment: Okay thank's for that guys my issue was that why npm wasn't installing properly so when i ran the command it wasn't server it i tried live-server and sometimes it says zsh: command not found, but I've managed to fix it but now I'm getting a new error in my console an ng-req error :S