# Load text file from site files

Tags: javascript

I need to load a text file in js, the text file is in the same dir as the .js file.

I found this code

```
var file = new XMLHttpRequest()
file.open("GET", "file.txt", true)
file.send()

file.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (file.readyState == 4 && file.status == 200) {
        console.log(file.responseText)
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work if I open my site locally ("file:///C:/site.html")

How can I load a text if it is run locally?  (Without using JQuery)

**EDIT**

I do not want to use JQuery but these are some questions with using JQuery.

"[Ajax in Jquery does not work from local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file)"
or
"[Jquery load() only working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996001/jquery-load-only-working-in-firefox)"

Comment: Run your script on a local server (like AMPPS, WAMP, MAMP, etc.) instead of from a directory. The reason is because most browsers prevent remotely downloaded HTML files that, when opened, have access to local files.

Answer (score 1):

The security policies of web browsers disallow getting file resources. You can, however, use JSONP to circumvent this:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = 'filename.txt';

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
function callback (data) {

}
```

You'll need `filename.txt` to look something like this:

```
callback('<text-file-content>')
```