# Javascript - getJSON to fetch data from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a data structure contained in a local Json file. I want to load it using `$.getJSON()`.

json file **locations.json**:

```
{locations:
    [{value: "Port Kelang",label: "Port Kelang",category: "Malaysia"},
     {value: "Pusan",label: "Pusan",category: "South Corea"},
     {value: "Qingdao",label: "Qingdao",category: "China"}]}
```

javascript file :

```
    $.getJSON("locations.json", function(data){
          //do something
    });
```

Using Chrome, I got an error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/locations.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

While I got another error in Firefox :

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: file:///E:/locations.json Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Host these files through another server. ftp maybe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax in Jquery does not work from local file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947971/ajax-in-jquery-does-not-work-from-local-file)

Comment: If you read Chrome's error message, it's telling you what's wrong. Also, your JSON is not well-formed, as Firefox is telling you. Property names must be quoted. See http://json.org/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan In fact, I got the same error in Firefox even if the property names are quoted.

Comment: ... then there's something else wrong with your JSON. Use a linting tool like http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure your JSON is JSON.

Answer (score 0):

for security reason, browsers don't allow cross origin request. I've face that issue while developping in local. That's an issue you wont have on remote server.
what i did, i disabled the same origin policy in my browser:
execute that if you are on mac:

```
 open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files
```

and this if you are on window:

```
"C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" –allow-file-access-from-files -disable-web-security
```